# How to display Error Message and its Fields from ModelState

Tags: c#, error-handling, .net-core-2.2

I have following codes for my Data

```
public class PersonDto 
{
    public string name ; 
    public DateTime dateOfBirth;
}
```

Now I have controller to save data.

Suppose I don't fill in the `dateOfBirth`, it will generate an error

```
[HttpPost("create")]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateClient([FromBody] PersonDto cpDto)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors);
        var message = string.Join(" | ", ModelState.Values
                .SelectMany(v => v.Errors)
                .Select(e => e.ErrorMessage));

        Console.WriteLine(message);
        return BadRequest(message);
    }

    ......... (other code)
}
```

Suppose I didn't enter the `dateOfBirth`, it should generate error right.

My problem is when I save the error message will be generated but it seems the `ErrorMessage` always empty string ==> `(" | ")`

If I go to debug mode, I can see which fields produce error but I don't know how to display which fields that generated error (just getting Invalid fields error message).

I have tried

```
return BadRequest(ModelState);
```

it also doesn't display which field caused the error.

Note: I use C# in .NET Core 2.2

Answer (score 1):

To get all error messages with their corresponding fields:

```
var errors = ModelState
    .Where(kv => kv.Value.Errors.Any())
    .Select(kv => new
    {
        Field = kv.Key,
        ErrorMessages = kv.Value.Errors.Select(e => e.ErrorMessage),
    });
```

`errors` will be a list that contains all the errors as anonymous objects with `Field` and `ErrorMessages`, if you want to get one string that contains the fields with their errors:

```
var errorsString = string.Join(" | ", errors
    .Select(e => $"Field: {e.Field}, Error: {string.Join(", ", e.ErrorMessages)}"));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 var messages = ModelState
                    .Where(x => x.Value.Errors.Count > 0)
                    .ToDictionary(
                        kvp => kvp.Key,
                        kvp => kvp.Value.Errors.Select(e => e.ErrorMessage).ToArray()
                    );
```

Change dto to :

```
 public class PersonDto
        {
            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter name")]
            public string name { get; set; }
            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter date")]
            public DateTime dateOfBirth { get; set; }
        }
```